# Merging node attributes onto igraph by an id

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following data:

```
> df
  source target weight
1      1      2      1
2      1      3      1
3      1      4      1
4      2      4      2
5      3      4      5
```

Rendered as a graph:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=TRUE)

> g
IGRAPH 99903f8 DNW- 4 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from 99903f8 (vertex names):
[1] 1->2 1->3 1->4 2->4 3->4
```

And the following metadata:

```
>  meta
  id    name
1  1    fred
2  2   sally
3  3    jill
4  4 eleanor
```

After it has been created an rendered into a graph, I'd like to add an additional data field to the nodes where the id of the source or target matches the id in meta.id data frame.

Unfortunately, what I'm doing now seems to produce a lot of extra matches.  How do I ask it to merge /only/ onto vertex attributes, and only where it matches?

For example, this doesn't seem to merge, just append everything:

```
> V(g)$name <- meta
> g
IGRAPH 99903f8 DNW- 4 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/x), weight (e/n)
+ edges from 99903f8 (vertex names):
[1] 1, 2, 3, 4->2, 4, 3, 1 1, 2, 3, 4->1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4->2, 4, 3, 1
[4] 2, 4, 3, 1->2, 4, 3, 1 1, 2, 3, 4->2, 4, 3, 1
```

### Update

It looked like this did the trick:

```
V(g)$name <- meta[V(g) == meta$id, c("name")]
```

But, I do actually need some kind of proper merge semantics.  In cases where there was a null, this fails badly.

```
1: In V(g) == meta$id :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In length(vattrs[[name]]) <- vc : length of NULL cannot be changed
3: In V(g) == meta$id :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In length(vattrs[[name]]) <- vc : length of NULL cannot be changed
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for `set_vertex_attr`:

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=TRUE) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("name", index = meta$id, value = meta$name)

g
#> IGRAPH 75f44e5 DNW- 4 5 -- 
#> + attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
#> + edges from 75f44e5 (vertex names):
#> [1] fred ->sally   fred ->jill    fred ->eleanor sally->eleanor
#> [5] jill ->eleanor

plot(g)
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(
    source = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),
    target = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 4),
    weight = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 5)
)

meta <- data.frame(
    id = 1:4,
    name = c("fred", "sally", "jill", "eleanor"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how that was done pre-pipe?  If I try to do this in 2 steps, I get `> set_vertex_attr("name", index = meta$id, value = meta$name)
Error in i_set_vertex_attr(graph = graph, name = name, index = index,  : 
  Not a graph object`

Comment: Got it: set.vertex.attribute(g, 'name', meta$id, meta$name)

Comment: @Mittenchops: indeed, without pipe operator you could write `g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE); g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", index = meta$id, value = meta$name)`.